# MassPay Paypal API Security Error

Tags: c#, .net, paypal

I am developing the mechanism where money is transferred in multiple accounts of paypal at once. It uses call to MassPay API by following code (credentials are scrambled).

```
        public static string TestMassPay()
    {
        //X509Certificate x509 = new X509Certificate("Certifcate Description");
        X509Certificate x509 = null;
        HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        string postData = "METHOD=MassPay&EMAILSUBJECT=You+have+money!&RECEIVERTYPE=EmailAddress&CURRENCYCODE=USD&L_EMAIL0=mr.kaleemullah%40gmail.com&L_Amt0=1.00&L_UNIQUEID0=&L_NOTE0=&USER=ali_api1.sevdotcom.ae&PWD=TLPPC43GDDM9DKZ9&SIGNATURE=Are9-8DOFiZXJtjX-8nkuOpzmTl2AQTy0kHQ5oey6i4QxuaeJ0z-Amhk&VERSION=1&SOURCE=1";

        objRequest.Timeout = TimeOut;

        objRequest.Method = "POST";

        objRequest.ContentLength = postData.Length;

        if (null != x509)
        {
            objRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(x509);

        }

        using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            myWriter.Write(postData);

        }

        using (WebResponse response = objRequest.GetResponse())
        {

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string strResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
                NameValueCollection qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(strResponse);
                return strResponse;
            }
        }
    }
```

It gives me following error

```
&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Security%20header%20is%20not%20valid
```

I have googled for the error as well but found nothing.

I think i need to give detail of security certificate about what i couldn't find anything in documentation.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `SUBJECT`; `SUBJECT` defines what account you're making the API call on behalf of (third-party access). "You've got money!" is not a valid account and hasn't granted you any permissions, hence the security error.

You're probably looking to use `EMAILSUBJECT` instead; see the [MassPay NVP API document](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/MassPay_API_Operation_NVP/) for more details.

Comment: I have also used EMAILSUBJECT not the Subject attribute, kindly check i think X509Certificate x509 = null; should be initialized but i don't know with which value

Comment: I would recommend using the .Net SDK from http://paypal.github.io/#merchant - it has a sample that shows you how to execute a MassPay: https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/Samples/PayPalAPISample/APICalls/MassPay.aspx.cs